# i confused, who fabric application is for?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

sorry, i am just beginner student studying fabric and . please, understand me, i do not use English well.. just i'm confused.. who is the application that was explained in http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html?highlight=node.js%20SDK for? client or just for invoking Systematically?

if the application is for invoking, any language is okay for coding client-side application?

Comment: why do you ask here and don't ask them directly?

Comment: Please ask your question in chat.hyperledger.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Writing your first application [tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/write_first_app.html) in Hyperledger Fabric's documentation is oriented to the application developer. It specifically targets a developer leveraging the Hyperledger Fabric SDK for Node.js. There are other language-specific [SDKs](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/fabric-sdks.html) available (e.g. Java) and others in development (Go and Python). There is also a command-line capability to interact with a Hyperledger Fabric blockchain network.